# QML module not found (QtCharts)

Tags: c++, qt

When I try to import QtCharts2.3 to .qml file, I encounter this error in Qt Creater.
I added '''Qt += charts''' to .pro file
and
I added '''using namespace QtCharts''' to mainwindow.h file
Do you have any solution?

Thanks to everyone. I solve this problem by resetuping Qt Creator.

Comment: Do you have QtCharts installed? this module does not come by default

Comment: Hi, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it will help us figure out your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`#include <QtCharts>` ?

Also, make sure it's installed via Qt Maintenance Tool

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Qt Charts from maintenancetool.exe